# How do I know when html2canvas is done?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I would like to know when html2canvas as fully rendered the capture and I can clean up changes I have made to the page.

If I reset style and position without a delay I get a half-resolution capture.

```
html2canvas(srcEl,
  {
    canvas: scaledCanvas,
    width: originalWidth,
    height: originalHeight
  }).then(function (canvas) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = "chart.png";
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  /*
  srcEl.style.position = '';
  srcEl.style.left = '';
  srcEl.style.top = '';
  */
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html2canvas 0.4 and below versions was used callback method onrendered. [Old documentation](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/v0.4/readme.md#usage) after 0.5 it was rewritten to use Promises [New documentation](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas#usage).

[Old way](https://jsfiddle.net/6bsonanz/)

```js
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }     
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis eleifend elit. Donec lectus sem, scelerisque sit amet facilisis quis, gravida a lacus. Nunc at lorem egestas, gravida lorem quis, pulvinar ante. Quisque id tempus libero. Mauris hendrerit nunc risus, ac laoreet lectus gravida et. Nam euismod magna ac enim posuere sagittis. Fusce at egestas enim, eu hendrerit enim.
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

[New way](https://jsfiddle.net/d5ksdxbL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onrendered` callback:

```
html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
    }
});
```

source: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html

Comment: Is that the same as the promise handler in version 5? https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: I don't know. But that version is only a dev build, so it may not work properly yet in any case

Comment: 0.5 seems to work better than 0.4 versions I had - at least I seemed to get a better result with a particular scaling up before capturing challenge. I could try 0.4 again and it might not have this timing issue.

Comment: I don't think the timing was the cause of my lack of clarity (in the images) there is a options.async which could ensure that rendering is complete. There is just some weird thing where I turn off the chrome debugger I get a different result. Both of the responses seem to be correct.