# How to drag and drop image into a div and save that div's new content as png?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `div` consisting of two `divs`. `div1` has a yellow background and a black border and under it is `div2` containing an image.

I want to drag and drop that image into `div1` and save all of it as a `png`.

The problem is that the saved image contains only the content of `div1` without the dropped image. I want to save the content of `div1` with the image also.

This is my code so far:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function dragDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var parent = ev.target.parentNode;
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = $("#contentImage"); // global variable
  var getCanvas; //global variable
  html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      getCanvas = canvas;
    }
  });

  $("#saveAsPNG").on('click', function() {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#convertToPNG").attr("download", "your_image.png").attr("href", newData);
  });
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

.div2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.image1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div">
    <div class="div1" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="contentImage">
    </div>
    <div class="div2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
      <img id="img2" class="image1" src="/path/to/image" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" width="160" height="160">
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <a id="saveAsPNG" href="#">convert to image</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your drag and drop code. The problem is with how `html2canvas` is being implemented. You are calling `html2canvas` as soon as the page is ready, and so there is obviously no image in `div1`.

See [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357805/18595321) for information how to use `html2canvas` properly.

I have made some changes to your code (changed the background color of the source `div` to pink and the color of the `image` to green). Click on the "convert to image" and a yellow `image` appears below. Now drag the green `image` to the yellow `div`, and then click "convert to image" again. A second yellow `image` appears next to the first with the green box included.

In this way, you can see that two images have been created. One without a green box and one with a green box.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function dragDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var parent = ev.target.parentNode;
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#saveAsPNG").on('click', function() {
    let element = $("#contentImage");
    html2canvas(element, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.div2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.image1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="saveAsPNG" href="#">convert to image</a>
  <div class="div">
    <div class="div1" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="contentImage">
    </div>
    <div class="div2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
      <img id="img2" class="image1" src="/path/to/image" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" width="160" height="160">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```